# Is $x^8+6x^7-15x^4-9x+12$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

As the title states, I'm trying to figure out whether $x^8+6x^7-15x^4-9x+12$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.
So far I have been introduced to the Rational Root Test/Theorem which has given me the following potential candidates for a root: $\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm6,\pm12\}$, none of which are *actually* a root.

The fact this is over $\mathbb{Q}$ makes me think maybe there is a rational solution, but I'm not sure how to figure it out. I've done some Googling already and found a lot of things I hadn't been introduced to yet (Eisenstein, for example).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yet the answer is immediate by Eisenstein criterion.

Comment: By the rational roots theorem, this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  You have checked all possible rational roots.

Comment: @ncmathsadist So does that mean each root of this polynomial is irrational? (I graphed it and it does have 4 roots).

Comment: @ncmathsadist: The rational roots theorem does no say it is irreducible, except for a quadratic or cubic polynomial.

Comment: For instance, $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ has no rational roots, but it is not irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$.

Comment: @Bernard, So can we say for $\text{degree}≥4$, for reducible of polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ applying of rational root theorem is sufficient condition ( if the rational roots exist), but not necessarily condition.?

Comment: I'd say the contrary: if a polynomial is irreducible, it necessarily has no rational root, but this is not a sufficient condition to be irreducible.

Comment: @Bernard thank you for explanation.

Comment: @Bernard But does this only apply to polynomials of degree greater than 4?  If the polynomial degree is less than 4, the existence of rational roots is necessary and sufficient condition. Is it correct to say that?

Comment: It works for degree $\ge 4$. For degrees $2$ and $3$, if the polynomial is not irreducible, it has a linear factor (at least).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that Eisenstein's criterion with $p=3$ aplies here immediately.

For a more basic attempt that requires some effort:

Let $p(x)=x^8+6x^7-15x^4-9x+12$.

Suppose that $p(x)=(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^6+ex^5+fx^4+gx^3+hx^2+ix+j)$. By the distributive law you will have a system of linear equations that you will shot that it has no rational roots.

Then suppose that $p(x)=(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)(ex^5+fx^4+gx^3+hx^2+ix+j)$ and do the same.

Then suppose that $p(x)=(ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e)(fx^4+gx^3+hx^2+ix+j)$ and do the same.

You have already checked that $p(x)$ has no rational roots hence these are all the cases you have to consider.

Comment: But for your 2nd case, $p(x)$ has degree 8, not 6; why can't $p(x)$ be the product of 2 **degree-4** polynomials. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot the degree while writing my solution

Answer (score 0):

Eisenstein is the best solution. After this, one could apply the modular criterion with $p=17$. The proof that the polynomial is irreducible over the finite field $\Bbb F_{17}$ also uses that we can write down a system of linear equations from some assumed decomposition. However, the system is easier to solve over $\Bbb F_{17}$ than over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: How did you find $17$? Trial and error? )

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Yes, because for some small $p$ there is an obvious root, e.g., for $p=3$ or $p=5$.